# Eclipse Java clean-up feature

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has an automatic Java clean up that is called:

> change indirect access to static members to direct access (accesses through subtypes)"`

What does it mean?

Edit: Note that there is another one that is

> change non-static access to static members using declaring type

so the subject of my inquiry has to be different from this.

These are in `Windows > Preferences > Java > CodeStyle > Clean-Up` which is almost impossible to find because it is under `Windows`.

Comment: That the static member will be called through the class in which it's declared.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think there is one that already does that.

Comment: My comment still stands. See my answer for an explanation on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have the class

```
class A {

    static int i;
}
```

Then

> change indirect access to static members to direct access (accesses through subtypes)

refers to a case where you have another class

```
class B extends A {}
```

and write

```
B.i = 2;
```

in which case the cleanup will change it to

```
A.i = 2;
```

since (as I wrote in my comment) the static member will be accessed through the class in which it's declared (`A`), and not through a class inheriting it (`B`).

> change non-static access to static members using declaring type

refers to a case where you write

```
A a = new A();
a.i = 2;
```

in which case the cleanup will change it to

```
A.i = 2;
```

since the static member will be accessed through the class (`A`) instead of through an instance of the class (`a`).

Answer (score 1):

This fixes up the case where you've got a static method in one class, but you're calling it using the name of a subclass.  So, the static method might be

```
SuperClass.someStaticMethod();
```

but you've referenced it as

```
SubClass.someStaticMethod();
```

Note that it's similar to another clean-up, where you call a static method, like `myObject.someStaticMethod();` in place of `TheClass.someStaticMethod();`.  The part in parentheses indicates that it's the "access through a subtype" clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your static variable/method through object instead of the class where it's defined. When it says 'by declaring type ' it means that you declared your variable/method as a class variable/method and you should call it by that.

Comment: But that sounds like the second one.

Comment: Both the errors are saying the same thing if you read them carefully. Compilers have multiple syntax error messages that are tiggered by different syntax errors. Sometimes a single syntax error tiggers two different error messages.

Comment: These are not errors. They are clean-up procedures. If there are multiple procedures then they must be different.

Comment: Sometimes more than one procedure tackles a single problem. Here, First one deals with Class members and is triggered because static member isn't called by its class as it should be. Second one deals with declaration procedure where you violate a declaration rule by non static calling of a static member when you delcared it as static.

Comment: "*Both the errors are saying the same thing if you read them carefully.*" Wrong, they deal with different types of accesses to `static` members. And it's also true that they are not errors, unless you went out of your way to configure your compiler as such, they are usually ignored of warnings.